# Firebase cloud function with access to two different projects

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I‘m currently developing two different web apps for university project, using Firebase for hosting, as database and Firebase cloud functions for some back-end work. I‘m using Firebase for the first time though.

Now, as the cloud function I have does the job for both projects, I do not want to deploy the function in both projects, but instead give the cloud function access to both projects.

Is there any way I can accomplish this?
What I tried so far was deploying cloud function to project A and there initializing two apps in my cloud function node.js environment, one with project A‘s firebaseConfig and one with project B‘s config. But I keep getting an error (permission denied: missing or insufficient permissions) when I tried to access the Firestore database of Project B. There are no specific rules set for database access as still in development, so that can‘t be the problem.
Can someone help me out?

Best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

- Project A

  - Service Account A
  - Cloud Function A running under the context of Service Account A
- Project B

  - Firestore B

If you want to have *Service Account A* access *Firestore B* then you must [grant *Service Account A* access to *Project B*](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/grant-service-account-access), then after it has been granted access you must [assign *Service Account A* a role](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions) that gives it permission to access *Firestore B*, for example:

- [Firebase Admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-predefined-all-products) (if you want to grant it broad permissions)
- [Cloud Datastore User](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#datastore-roles) (if you only need it to read/write Firestore data)

Without proper IAM permissions in place you cannot have cross-project access.

Comment: Ahh okay I understand, I think I found a nice article as well explaining how to create this service account and grant it the required permissions & roles as I did not work with them so far! Will try it out within next days and post it, if helpful.

Comment: But two more questions: When having the service account and cross-project access setup, accessing both projects is done by initializing two apps one with A‘s firebaseConfig and one with B‘s config as I already tried, right?
Secondly, with cross-project access setup can I still use any function trigger in cloud function? E.g: firestore.Doc.onCreate()? Think I stumbled over an article, stating it‘s not possible?

Comment: You should make a new post for questions like that where you can elaborate on precisely what you mean.

Comment: Okay, will do that! Thank you for your answers!